# Does signing out of my Apple ID delete the apps on macOS?

Tags: mac-appstore

I have some apps that I bought personally that I would like to use on my work laptop.

Can I sign in with my Apple ID and then install these app versions there and then sign out?

I guess I would not receive any updates for them that way?

Comment: Are you allowed to install additional software on your work computer?

Comment: Yes, no specific policies there and even if there were I think apps from the Mac App Store would have a leg up in most situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to give your Apple ID password in order to update them.

You are allowed to install apps on 5 Macs. I suppose a work laptop is OK as long as you are the prime or only user. You may want to check the exact wording of the Apple licence agreement in your country.

Answer (score 0):

No, signing out does not delete the apps on macOs.
And yes signing in will allow you to install them, provided you do not exceed the required number of computers; beware different HD OS count as different computers.